# Sql Server License choice optimization

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out which is the best option to use for SQL server License.

I have done my research but still cannot find out the best option for my application, here are my search results.

- **Enterprise** - Operating system maximum in all aspects, very costly.
- **Standard** - Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores, 128 GB RAM limitation. Much cheaper than Enterprise edition but still fairly pricey.
- **Web** - Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores, 64 GB RAM limitation. A bit cheaper than Standard.

I am just wondering about the CPU limitation, will it be abled to handle 20k + users total and up to 5k concurrent users with this CPU limit on both Web and Standard?

or I absolutely need to buy the enterprise edition for this number of users?

Given the application is fairly heavy on database consumption,
also given that the server has 32 cores.

in **Brief** what I am asking "**is 16 Cores sufficient to handle 5k concurrent users in a heavy database consumption system? , and if not 24  cores Will be sufficient?**  "

Comment: I would suggest you make a list of "MUST HAVES" (for at least next 2-3 Years) for your application and see what is the cheapest option available to you that gives you all of your "MUST HAVES", there is no limit to how much you can spend on a license but when you are making such decision get the business involved. Give them all the options with price tags and let them decide how much they want to spend. What you dont want is going for a cheaper option and then down the road telling business that they cannot do something because you made them purchase a cheaper license, let them make this decisi

Comment: Licencing is explicitly off-topic on [so], sorry. Any case, this is very dependent on your use case and actual hardware, so we'd need more infor even if we wanted to answer this

Comment: @M.Ali I am not inquiring about SQL server fetchers in each category, I am only asking about the CPU Limit, is it sufficient to handle 5k concurrent users with only 16 or 24 cores ?

Comment: It totally depends on your application and user behavior. The only way to find out is to measure it, or perhaps compare with a very similar app. There are apps where Standard is sufficient for 5k concurrent users, and there's apps where it's insufficient for 100 concurrent users. Option 1) assume Standard, adjust as needed. Option 2) if your budget allows, plan for Enterprise, adjust as needed. Option 3) Use Developer until you can load test it and estimate what's neeeded.

Comment: fwiw here's some numbers https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/11/how-much-memory-is-normal-for-sql-servers/ but as you'll see it's more about data size than users, which probably indicates that's what you should think about more.

Comment: I dont think anyone can answer this question without some testing. The best thing to do is to setup a test environment, and load test it. If you think you will get 5K concurrent connections, load test it with 15K connections and monitor the performance of you app and see how SQL CPU is doing when you are hitting it with 15k connections. Doing things like that will give you some indication whether 16 or 24 core or maybe less or more is needed.